# Filling in missing values from other dataframe with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, merge, conditional-statements, fillna

I am trying to fill the missing value from other dataframe with matching column values and conditions.

The two Dataframes that I'm working with looks like below:

The First Dataframe contains values that are recorded in Quarter periods (Mar.-June-Sep.-Dec.)

| Name | Date | Value_1 | Value_2 | Value_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2022-03 | 1 | 5 | 9 |
| John | 2022-06 | 2 | NA | 10 |
| John | 2022-09 | NA | 7 | 11 |
| John | 2022-12 | 4 | 8 | 12 |
| Dave | 2021-03 | NA | 5 | 10 |
| Dave | 2021-06 | 20 | NA | 10 |
| Dave | 2021-09 | 10 | 5 | 8 |
| Dave | 2021-12 | NA | NA | 30 |

The Second Dataframe contains values that are recorded in Semiannual periods (June and Dec.)

| Name | Date | Value_1 | Value_2 | Value_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2022-06 | NA | NA | 30 |
| John | 2022-12 | 50 | NA | NA |
| Dave | 2021-06 | NA | NA | NA |
| Dave | 2021-12 | 30 | 20 | 10 |

There are two things that I want to put as a condition when merging this two Dataframe.

(1.) If the 'Value_1' and 'Value_3' of Semiannual column is missing, replace with values in Quarterly Dataframe by same Year and Month. For example, the Value_3 second column will be '12' since the Value'_3, forth row in Quarter dataframe has the value 12. In this case when filling the values, values in March and September in quarter data will be ignored.

(2.) If the 'Value_2' of Semiannual column is missing, repace the values in Quarterly Dataframe by adding the relavant months. For example, the Value_2 second column (2022-12) in Semiannual Dataframe will be replace with the value by adding 2022-09 and 2022-12 in Quarterly dataframe.

The Final Dataframe will look like below:

| Name | Date | Value_1 | Value_2 | Value_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2022-06 | 2 (from quarter df) | 5 (5 + NA from quarter df) | 30 |
| John | 2022-12 | 50 | 15 (7 + 8 from quarter df) | 12 (from quarter df |
| Dave | 2021-06 | 20 (from quarter df) | NA (NA + NA from quarter df) | 10 (from quarter df) |
| Dave | 2021-12 | 30 | 20 | 10 |

I am trying to develop the code below, but it only satisfies the first condition.

```
dt_quarter= [['John','2022-03',1,5,9], ['John','2022-06',2,'NA',10], ['John','2022-09','NA',7,11], ['John','2022-12',4,8,12],
         ['Dave','2021-03','NA',5,10], ['Dave','2021-06',20,'NA',10], ['Dave','2021-09',10,5,8], ['Dave','2021-12','NA','NA',30]]
df_quarter= pd.DataFrame(dt_quarter, columns=['Name','Date','Value_1','Value_2','Value_3'])

dt_semi= [['John','2022-06','NA','NA',30], ['John','2022-12',50,'NA','NA'],
         ['Dave','2021-06','NA','NA','NA'], ['Dave','2021-12',30,20,10]]
df_semi= pd.DataFrame(dt_semi, columns=['Name','Date','Value_1','Value_2','Value_3'])

group_cols = ['Name', 'Date']

df_combined = df_semi.set_index(group_cols).fillna(df_quarter.set_index(group_cols)).reset_index()
```

Please give advice on this problem.
Thanks

Comment: It would be better to add your code to create dataframe, so we can create a sample easily to better answer your question

Comment: @masoud sorry for that, I just added the code